# Erro HTTP Status 404 - The requested resource is not available no Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Ja tentei varias formas de resolução desse problema, mas quando eu clico para que o controlador acesse a url ele da erro. Segue os arquivos

**Controlador**

```
package com.br.maco.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/home",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView home()
    {
        ModelAndView mc = new ModelAndView();
        mc.setViewName("index");
        return mc;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/cadastro",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView cadastro()
    {
        ModelAndView md = new ModelAndView();
        md.setViewName("cadastrar");
        return md;
    }

}
```

**Servlet**:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.br.maco" />

<bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InterSnalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<mvc:annotation-driven />

</beans>
```

**Web**:

```xml
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"     xmlns:javaee="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
version="3.0">

    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring-web</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring-web</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

**pom.xml**:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.br.maco</groupId>
<artifactId>Mr</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Mr Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <jdk.version>1.6</jdk.version>
    <spring.version>3.2.13.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
        <version>9.3.1.v20150714</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- embedded Jetty server, for testing -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>9.2.11.v20150529</version>
            <configuration>
                <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
                <webApp>
                    <contextPath>/spring3</contextPath>
                </webApp>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- configure Eclipse workspace -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
                <wtpContextName>spring3</wtpContextName>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
 </build>

 </project>
```

**index.jsp**:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sistema de Solicitação de Prontuários</title>

    <link href="resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="resources/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <img alt="Bootstrap Image Preview"
                    src="http://lorempixel.com/140/140/" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <h3>Sistema de Solicitação de Prontuários</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                    <li class="active"><a href="home">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="cadastro">Cadastrar Solicitações</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Consultar Solicitaçãoes</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown pull-right"><a href="#"
                        data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Opções<strong
                            class="caret"></strong></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Mudar senha</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Sair</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="resources/js/jquery.min.js" /></script>
    <script src="resources/js/bootstrap.min.js" /></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Onde está <context:component-scan base-package="com.br.maco" /> coloque <context:component-scan base-package="com.br.maco*" /> Com asterisco no final. Da forma que você colocou o Container do Spring só vai procurar no pacote com.br.maco e seu controller está no pacote com.br.maco.controller

Comment: A alteração deu certo?

Comment: Não funcionou !